# Inequality for all real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I am trying to prove a hw problem from Taos Analysis 1 book.  I would like some help proving the following statements if they are true which I do not necessarily believe.

Let $x,y \in \Bbb R$. Show that $x \le y+\epsilon$ for all real numbers $\epsilon \gt 0$ if and only if $x \le y$.
I believe it should read $x \lt y+\epsilon $.

I also need to show $|x-y| \le \epsilon$ for all real numbers $\epsilon \gt 0$ if and only if $x=y$.

I believe it should read $|x-y| \lt \epsilon$.

If the statements are written like I believe I know how to prove them.  Otherwise I am not sure.

Comment: doesn't really matter, if $x \leq y + \epsilon$ then $x < y+(2 \epsilon)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the statements are true as stated. For example, if $x \leq y$ then certainly $x \leq y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, and on the other hand, if $x > y$, then $x > y+\frac{x-y}{2}$, where $\frac{x-y}{2} > 0$, since $x - (y + \frac{x-y}{2}) = \frac{x-y}{2} > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out.

Now if $x\le y + \epsilon $ for all $\epsilon>0$ then three cases occur.

First $x-y \lt 0$ which implies $y \ge x$.

Second $x=y$ which again implies $y \ge x$.

Thirdly $x-y \gt 0$ if this occurs then because $x-y \in \mathbb R$ we have $0\lt \frac{1}{n} \lt x-y$. So choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$, but this contradicts assumption that $x-y\le \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ therefore $x-y \not\gt 0$ and falls into one of the first two cases.